# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code - Xcode 15.0

Tags: xcode, react-native

I'm using M2 MacBook Air chip and xCode . I get the following React Native error while executing the app in the simulator:

> The following build commands failed:
> PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ Specs /User.../FBReactNativeSpec.build/Script-46EB2E110.sh (in target 'FBReactNativeSpec' from project 'Pods')
> (1 failure)

The problem persists even when I start a brand-new React Native project and try to execute it on iOS. What led to the error and how can it be fixed?

Thank you

Updates:
below is my config settings of react-native info :

info Fetching system and libraries information...

```
System:
    OS: macOS 14.1
    CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M2
    Memory: 498.81 MB / 24.00 GB
    Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
  Binaries:
    Node: 18.18.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.19 - /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
    npm: 9.8.1 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2023.09.25.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.13.0 - /opt/homebrew/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 23.0, iOS 17.0, macOS 14.0, tvOS 17.0, watchOS 10.0
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2022.2 AI-222.4459.24.2221.10121639
    Xcode: 15.0/15A240d - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 19.0.1 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 17.0.2 => 17.0.2 
    react-native: 0.66.4 => 0.66.4 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

Done Procedures:

1. Product Destination choose Show Rosetta
2. Linker flags add `-ld64`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code to your Podfile inside post_install and install pods again

```
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
       target.build_configurations.each do |config|
         config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)', '_LIBCPP_ENABLE_CXX17_REMOVED_UNARY_BINARY_FUNCTION']
       end
     end
```

for example my podfile

```
  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      # Set `mac_catalyst_enabled` to `true` in order to apply patches
      # necessary for Mac Catalyst builds
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
           target.build_configurations.each do |config|
             config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)', '_LIBCPP_ENABLE_CXX17_REMOVED_UNARY_BINARY_FUNCTION']
           end
         end
  end
end
```